# Wordpress Theme Customization tags

Tags: wordpress, themes, customization

I have a question about dooplay wordpress theme ?
how to enable card option in dooplay wordpress theme . with refrence to the attached image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another posts and view post count numbers in elementor your cards.

Comment: Hi. Instead of using an "answer" to ask if they can provide more information, use a "comment" instead.